# Android Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android

How can i close navigation drawer after click navigation listView item?as this point it only open new fragment in background.but navigation drawer didn't close.any help... !!!

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, 
                mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Set the default content area to item 0
        // when the app opens for the first time
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            navigateTo(0);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void navigateTo(int position) {
        Log.v(TAG, "List View Item: " + position);
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    Fragment_home.newInstance(),
                    Fragment_home.TAG).commit();
            break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  private void navigateTo(int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "List View Item: " + position);
    switch(position) {
    case 0:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                Fragment_home.newInstance(),
                Fragment_home.TAG).commit();
         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        break;
```